# Parsing a string to individual words

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing, string-parsing

I'm looking at writing a function that parses a given string input and separates the string into its constituents (as defined by one or more space characters).

Unfortunately, I have had no real experience with string parsing, so any help would be really appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: You didn't ask an actual question. Also SO is not a coding service, so you need to try something and show where you are having trouble with it. If you are completely unclear on what to do then using a search engine is the first step (or consulting your notes and/or teacher if this is for a course/class).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have a starting point now in the form of the functions mentioned in the other comments. In the next little while I'll go back and have a solid crack at it and let you know how I go :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to strsep(3) too, since it is "intended as a replacement    for the strtok() function."

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?strsep(3)

Comment: It's not a standard C function though and since OP did not specify a specific compiler or OS it might not be available

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t string_parser( const char *input, char *word_array[] ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *input )
    {
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*input ) ) ++input;
        if ( *input )
        {
            word_array[n++] = ( char * )input;
            while ( *input && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*input ) ) ++input;
        }           
    }

    return n;
}  

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello Sam Talbot. How do you do?";
    char * word_array[N];

    size_t n = string_parser( s, word_array );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( word_array[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello Sam Talbot. How do you do?
Sam Talbot. How do you do?
Talbot. How do you do?
How do you do?
do you do?
you do?
do?
```

Another approach to defining the function is to allocate dynamically the array of words inside the function. In this case the function declaration can look like

```
size_t string_parser( const char *input, char ***word_array )
```

You should at first count the words using one loop and then in another loop fill the array of words.

For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t string_parser( const char *input, char ***word_array) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    const char *p = input;

    while ( *p )
    {
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
        n += *p != '\0';
        while ( *p && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
    }

    if ( n )
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        *word_array = malloc( n * sizeof( char * ) ); 

        p = input;

        while ( *p )
        {
            while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
            if ( *p )
            {
                const char *q = p;
                while ( *p && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

                size_t length = p - q;

                ( *word_array )[i] = ( char * )malloc( length + 1 );

                strncpy( ( *word_array )[i], q, length );
                ( *word_array )[i][length] = '\0';

                ++i;
            }
        }           
    }

    return n;
}  

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello Sam Talbot. How do you do?";
    char ** word_array = NULL;

    size_t n = string_parser( s, &word_array );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( word_array[i] );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( word_array[i] );
    free( word_array );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
Sam
Talbot.
How
do
you
do?
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your demonstrative Program - it is very helpful. A question about the second example, it appears that you use a triple pointer to word_array in the function. I am struggling to see how this works. Would you be able to help me understand it's use in this example? Thanks!

Comment: @SamTalbot If you want that the argument would be changed in a function you have to pass it indirectly by reference/ Otherwise all arguments are passed by value and the function will deal with a copy of its argument.

Comment: Ah, okay. This makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), this does what you require.

You need to at least attempt this on your own.